# Finding the pair of nodes with maximum distance in an arbitrary rooted tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, trees, graph-traversal

Suppose we are given an arbitrary rooted tree. We want to find two nodes that have the maximum distance among all pairs of nodes. I am looking for an algorithm with time complexity $\mathcal{O}(n)$, where $n$ is the number of nodes in the tree. Note that there may be more than one pair of nodes that satisfy this condition, but finding any one pair is enough.

Also, I am writing code in Java, and the input format is as follows: the first line gives the number of nodes, and the next $n-1$ lines give two numbers $u_i$ and $v_i$ each, indicating that there is an edge between nodes $u_i$ and $v_i$. What would be a good data structure to store and represent the rooted tree for this problem and implement the algorithm?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about java, but there could be several ways to represent the tree:

- an array of $n$ adjacency lists, like an undirected graph;
- an array of $n$ integers, that contains the parent of each node (and so that the root is its own parent);
- an inductive structure, with a node and the list of its children.

The idea of the algorithm is simple:

- find a leaf $x$ of maximum depth;
- find the farthest node $y$ of $x$ (either by using BFS, or by finding a leaf of maximum depth in the tree rooted in $x$).

Let $V$ be the set of nodes of the tree.

To prove that $d(x, y) = \max\limits_{u,v \in V^2}d(u, v)$, consider $u$ and $v$ two nodes that maximize $d(u, v)$, and $w$ be their lowest common ancestor and consider two cases:

- if $w$ is an ancestor of $x$, then let $z$ be the lowest common ancestor between $u$ and $x$ (without loss of generality). Since $x$ has greater depth than $u$, then:
  $$d(u, v) = d(u, w) + d(w, v) \leqslant d(x, w) + d(w, v) = d(x, v)$$

  [image]
- if $w$ is not an ancestor of $x$, then let $z$ be the lowest common ancestor between $w$ and $x$. Since $x$ has greater depth than $w$, then:
  $$d(u, v) = d(u, w) + d(w, v) \leqslant d(u, z) + d(w, v) \leqslant d(x, w) + d(w, v) = d(x, v)$$

  [image]

In both case, the maximum distance can be reach with $x$ as one of the two nodes, which proves the correction of the algorithm.

Comment: I highly appreciate you for this answer. It looks great. But I have two problems. 1) How can I find the leaf with maximum depth. 2) I guess I can't understand the correct meaning of this sentence: "or by finding a leaf of maximum depth in the tree rooted in $x$". You mean I reverse the tree and assume that $x$ is the root an do what I did for step 1?

Comment: You can compute the depth of each node, either by running a BFS from the root, or (it is the same idea) by computing it recursively: the depth of a node is $1$ plus the depth of its parent (except for the root, which is of depth $0$). And yes, given a tree, you can compute the tree rooted in any node in linear time.